# TensorFlow Conv2D implementation?

Tags: tensorflow, eigen, tensorflow-xla

I'm trying to find where the implementation of an actual Conv2D operation is so I can assess memory access patterns. Tracing things around, it looks like execution of a Conv2D operation enters Eigen with a `contract()` function call. The problem is, I can't seem to find the definition or declaration of the function in either TensorFlow or Eigen source.

What functions are largely responsible for the execution of a Conv2D operation in TensorFlow? I'd like to see how it is paralyzed, what the general memory access pattern is, and how the raw computations are done.

This query is for CPU specifically, as I've already looked into GPU execution to a degree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some searching, I found actual implementation of CPU Conv2D is in [deep_conv2d.cc](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/deep_conv2d.cc#L935).

Comment: Do you know what is the difference between Deep and Direct convolution that are implemented in this file?

Answer (score 0):

I think Conv2dCPU is implemented in this file using Eigen [conv ops Line 61 onwards](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/conv_ops.cc#L61)

Comment: Not really, that's setup for the operation (calling a few optimized methods for simplified cases). Notice the call to  `functor::SpatialConvolution<Device, T>()(ctx->eigen_device<Device>(), output->tensor<T, 4>(), input.tensor<T, 4>(), filter.tensor<T, 4>(), row_stride, col_stride, padding)` in the final `else`. This begins a winding path of function calls that I can't seem to trace to some sort of structure that looks to be actually doing multiplications/for loops, etc.

Comment: You may look at https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/conv_ops.cc#L277

Answer (score 0):

`contract()` returns an abstract expression whose evaluation is implemented in [TensorContraction.h](https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/src/8d1ccfd9c5a0bf1a662bd0fe35858f4e527d2bac/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/src/Tensor/TensorContraction.h?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#TensorContraction.h-175). It is essentially a wrapper on top of Eigen's matrix-matrix or matrix-vector products.